# How to make QTP automation tool to recognise salesforce object?

Tags: automation

I was trying to automate a SF application using QTP by record and run method.
but QTP was unable to recognise the objects present in the application.
Kindly guide how to deal with the situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the forum. This is not the right forum to answer this question. Ask this on stackoverflow.

Comment: Which version of the browser you are using ? and which version of QTP it is ? QTP 11 works till IE 9.0 and UFT 11.53 works till IE 10.0.